# java Swing, Como agregar un jcombobox a un jpanel seteando la distribucion Bolso de Rejilla mediante codigo?

Tags: java, java-swing

La idea sería que cuando agrego el combo le configure también al distribución bolso de regilla dando el peso de x en 1 y el dey en 0 en la distribución del Jpanel.

```
//El código sería  el siguiente
JComboBox cmbNomDocumentoJEP = new JComboBox();
jPanel17.add(cmbNomDocumentoJEP);
```

Comment: Se más específico en tu pregunta, dado que no se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: claro amigo , el dilema es el siguiente , como setear un gestor de distribucion al jpanel desde codigo puesto tengo agregar el combo dinamicamente pero como no estoy seteando el gestor de distribucion se muestra visualmente desproporcionado cuando se ejecuta la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos amigos encontré esta solución y funciono bien al ejecutar la pantalla.
//aqui se le agrega la distribucion de bolso de regilla con mayor peso en X

```
   JComboBox cmbNomDocumentoJEP = new JComboBox();

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();   
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 0;

    jPanel17.add(cmbNomDocumentoJEP, c);
```